# Django Admin search_fields - How do I specify a max length?

Tags: django, django-admin

The django model admin objects allow you to specify fields for searching via the search_fields key, and they appear as text search boxes in the top of the list view.

However I noticed these fields do not have a maxlength attribute listed on them, so I am wondering if this is a bug, or if there is a way for me to specify the max length on this field so I do not get query strings that are way too long.

I expected these fields to be limited to the length of the value of said field, but it is not.

How do I specify a maxlength on a search_fields input on the list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/search_form.html) for the template code of the search form. The code in line 6 gives us no way to customize the maxlength attribute or add any other attribute from Django's API.

```
<input type="text" size="40" name="{{ search_var }}" value="{{ cl.query }}" id="searchbar" />
```

If you really want to add maxlength attribute or any other attribute, there are two ways (that I can think of) to do that.

1. Override admin templates and add the necessary attribute (relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and sample video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZxEA6Hwr4A))
2. Add javascript to your ModelAdmins and manipulate the DOM (relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions))